# Applescript play track spotify

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify

I want to play a track by running an applescript. I'm having trouble figuring out the play track method.

I'm doing this

```
tell application "Spotify"
    play track "One Thing" in context spotify:track:5Up9Lj7QWudEfMc0ve5qWW
end tell
```

that obviously doesn't work.  I don't know what to do with the context part. What is a context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation in the AppleScript editor. `Track` and `context` are both URIs. A Spotify context is a container, and the client defaults to using the track's album.

So, for example, both of these will play the track in the context of its album (they're functionally the same):

```
tell application "Spotify"
     play track "spotify:track:5Up9Lj7QWudEfMc0ve5qWW"
end tell

tell application "Spotify"
     play track "spotify:track:5Up9Lj7QWudEfMc0ve5qWW" in context "spotify:album:33yaWg4n9max6UWPlD59zs"
end tell
```

However, you could also play a track in the context of an artist:

```
tell application "Spotify"
     play track "spotify:track:5Up9Lj7QWudEfMc0ve5qWW" in context "spotify:artist:2AsusXITU8P25dlRNhcAbG"
end tell
```

Or even a playlist!

```
tell application "Spotify"
    play track "spotify:track:3NN3bw0UMt3DbFUVGh78kV" in context "spotify:user:sweetlelle:playlist:6C7spm3ZSJSWL9EZAhiMFb"
end tell
```

Comment: is there a way to play in context of your music?

Comment: how do you get the playlist id?